# Do I need to reindex mysql table after bulk delete?

Tags: mysql, innodb, delete, performance, performance-tuning

I have a table in MySQL with a lot of INSERT and SELECT at every second. And there is a bulk delete of some older data once in a day. Do I need to reindex the table after delete? I want to increase the performance. Can anybody suggest some tips? Using 'innodb' as the storage engine. Do I need to change it? I think its better for concurrent insert and select. Please give your suggestions. Do I need to do reindexing?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 13):

Do you need to optimize the tables when using InnoDB? Yes and no, depending on your workload and if you are encountering performance problems or not.

A shameless copy-paste from the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimize-table.html) :

> For InnoDB tables, OPTIMIZE TABLE is mapped to ALTER TABLE, which
>   rebuilds the table to update index statistics and free unused space in
>   the clustered index. This is displayed in the output of OPTIMIZE TABLE
>   when you run it on an InnoDB table, as shown here:
>
> ```
> mysql> OPTIMIZE TABLE foo;
> +----------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
> | Table    | Op       | Msg_type | Msg_text                                                          |
> +----------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
> | test.foo | optimize | note     | Table does not support optimize, doing recreate + analyze instead |
> | test.foo | optimize | status   | OK                                                                |
> +----------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
> ```
>
> This operation does not use fast index creation. Secondary indexes are
>   not created as efficiently because keys are inserted in the order they
>   appeared in the primary key. See Section 14.14.6, “Limitations of Fast
>   Index Creation”.
>
> InnoDB stores data using a page-allocation method and does not suffer
>   from fragmentation in the same way that legacy storage engines (such
>   as MyISAM) will. When considering whether or not to run optimize,
>   consider the workload of transactions that your server will process:
>
> - Some level of fragmentation is expected. InnoDB only fills pages 93% full, to leave room for updates without having to split pages.
> - Delete operations might leave gaps that leave pages less filled than desired, which could make it worthwhile to optimize the table.
> - Updates to rows usually rewrite the data within the same page, depending on the data type and row format, when sufficient space is
>     available. See Section 14.10.5, “How Compression Works for InnoDB
>     Tables” and Section 14.12.1, “Overview of InnoDB Row Storage”.
> - High-concurrency workloads might leave gaps in indexes over time, as InnoDB retains multiple versions of the same data due through its MVCC
>     mechanism. See Section 14.5.12, “InnoDB Multi-Versioning”.

Answer (score 7):

You could reindex the table and even shrink the table. However, if you want to delay such disk-based maintenance, you should, at the very least, recompute the index statistics.

Without recomputing the index statistics, the MySQL Query Optimizer may make bad choices for query EXPLAIN plans. This could adversely affect SELECTs if the statistics for nonexist data is still present. This is true for both MyISAM and InnoDB.

You don't have to shrink the the table to compute the index statistics, although it will be better for overall performance.

To compute statistics for all indexes in a table, [**you would run**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/analyze-table.html)

```
ANALYZE TABLE tablename;
```

You could do this every night. It will not attempt to do any defragmenting or shrinkage of data. You could probably do that once a week by running `OPTIMIZE TABLE tablename;`. This will also do the `ANALYZE TABLE tablename;` for you after the shrinkage of the table's physical file (`.ibd` for InnoDB or `.MYI` for MyISAM) or.

Answer (score 3):

OPTIMIZE TABLE is almost never needed on InnoDB.

Are you DELETEing records based on age?  If so, you can make the "bulk delete" essentially free by using PARTITIONing and DROP PARTITION.  More details here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint